# Play 2 songs simultaneously,one should play only through Headphones and other through Speakers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am using  AVPlayer to play two songs simultaneously.

I want to play song on Speaker and before playing i want to check it in headphones only(another song will be playing at the same time in speakers) then i want to play on speakers.Its like prelistening of a song before routing it to Speakers.

Is it Possible on iOS..?

Comment: vakio: If it's possible, can you suggest how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say this would only be possible  by used private APIS (if at all) once the iPhone has headphones plugged in everything is routed to it so you'd be trying to change a low-level setting.

Comment: Not sure, but you could read through these: https://github.com/kennytm/iphone-private-frameworks